# Jasmine How to test a function that returns an anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following code in a service.

```
function getK(k) {
        return function() {
            return k;
        };
    }
```

I can test that getK was called with

```
beforeEach(inject(function(FiltersService){
    this.service = FiltersService;
    spyOn(this.service, 'getK');
}));

it("getK should be called", function(){
    var key = "TEST";
    var result = this.service.getK(key);
    expect(this.service.getK).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(this.service.getK).toHaveBeenCalledWith("TEST");
}
```

My question is how do I test the inner

```
return function() {
    return k;
}
```

With Jasmine

**EDIT**

To try and further specify, the `getK function` is used to fill in an object as shown below. That object is part of a library that I am using that uses `key`. I guess I am a little confused on how to test this from a karma-jasmine perspective seeing that the actual implementation of `key` is part of a library that I do not control. So I am not sure how to write tests for the internal getK function or even for the below `valid` function to be sure the object is filled out properly

```
libObject.push({
   Data: {
   Name: 'test'  
            },
   key: getK("TEST"),
     valid: function() {
     return true;
}
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: All that I really can test. That it returns what I sent to getK...honestly it's to get the code coverage up

Comment: `expect(result).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function))`. You haven't provided the details on the context of this function, so it is not possible to say anything else. And I don't see why 'test that getK was called with' is needed. It was you who've called `getK(key)`. Of course it will be called, of course with 'TEST'.

Comment: Edited the question to try and help explain the situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unit testing supposes testing the code line by line for full coverage.

Considering that `getK` is exposed as `FiltersService` method, it is

```
expect(this.service.getK).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));

var key = {};
var result = this.service.getK(key);

expect(result).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
expect(result()).toBe(key);
```

There's no need for a spy in this spec, because there's nothing to spy.

Answer (score 2):

Since calling the parent function returns a function, call the parent function, and immediately call the anonymous function returned by the parent:

```
expect(service.getK(k)()).toEqual(k);
```

This is very simple and should work perfectly for you.